# Smalltalk Learning Project: Any recommendation?

Tags: smalltalk

Currently I am learning Smalltalk. I do this because I want to learn as much as I can in one week about a new programming language in order to improve my skills. Next week I will try something else.

So far I am able to read Smalltalk code but I have a very limited experience in writing. Can you recommend me any small size project that will help me understand better this language in a short time period?

Answer (score 3):

Look into a book [Squeak by Example](http://www.squeakbyexample.org), there are many examples to work on and practice. After a while you'll be very well prepared for some real, yet mini project.

I think you need only few days for a book with examples, so this is well spend time even if you have just one week.

Comment: I am reading Squeak by Example but I am searching for a side project.

Comment: We are just chatting on #squeak at irc.freenode.org about your question. Do you have any preference, what kind of project you'd like?

Comment: Small size. I should be able to make something functional in less than a week. Thanks!

Comment: Do you something involving Aida or Seaside is a better idea for a beginner project?

Comment: Hard to say. You need to grasp even more new concepts in a short time. Try Aida tutorial (which is short) and in the meantime you can get some idea for small web project.

Another idea is to make a matrix multiplication in Smalltalk. A good exercise of polymorphism and other nicelities of Smalltalk

Answer (score 2):

I really, really like [The Laser Game Tutorial](http://squeak.preeminent.org/tut2007/html/index.html)

> Tutorial: Squeak Development Example for Squeak 3.9
>
> A.K.A. "The Laser Game Tutorial"
>   This excellent tutorial by Stephan Wessels will guide 
>   you through installing Squeak, to creating a fun game using the Morphic graphics system, all > while observing solid object-oriented design principles

It is divided in 6 Sessions so 1 each day although I must say each session has taken me two hours or so.

Perfect for your objectives.

Answer (score 1):

Anything not too trivial goes well. If you plan going on squeak, I'd propose you to write a card game, lottery or something else such.

It'd be more useful for you to find out some example code though. What prevents you from writing C in smalltalk?

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at Programming with robots.

I think the [BotsInc](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCwQFjACahUKEwjD5K_k-JPJAhWFMBoKHXqJD7o&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgforge.inria.fr%2Ffrs%2Fdownload.php%2F10764%2FBotsInc-OriginalEnglish.pdf&usg=AFQjCNGnxxCTfhMrzMSaMxvRmAdDGm_lug&sig2=wgnlJGA6JoJ-Ff8GoB4aLg) material can be mastered in one week - although the time taken can vary. There is a [Free book](http://squeak.org/documentation/) version for download available. And for small real world projects there is [NXTalk](http://haupz.blogspot.com/2008/11/its-alive.html) announced for
early this year.

Answer (score 1):

Just do whatever you'd do in the language you already know. Taking a small task like writing a simple TODO list or even simple blog will undoubtedly improve your Smalltalk skills.

And remember to be easy on yourself. Expecting too much too soon can be intimidating.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to try something different, check out GNU Smalltalk Koans at http://skim.la/gnu_smalltalk_koans/, a set of tests to teach you Smalltalk  in the tradition of Edgecase's Ruby Koans and Python Koans.

It promises to incrementally deepen your understanding of the language through tests.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the The Laser Game Tutorial. (that  I recommended in my previous answer)

There is the "[The Bowling Game](http://ronjeffries.com/xprog/articles/bowlingforsmalltalk/)"

> Article: Discovering Better Code
>   Series
>
> A.K.A. "The Bowling Example" A guided
>   tour through the mind of a
>   Smalltalker: How to build a business
>   model from the ground up, factoring it
>   along the way. If you don't understand
>   how Smalltalkers think or why they
>   think that way, you need to read this
>   series.

The really nice thing about this project is that it is like being the pair-programmer of a great developer.

The author Ron Jeffries is one of tho founders of Extreme Programming and a book author.

So it is a really good resource. I wish more tutorials where written like this.

Answer (score 0):

I really enjoyed Ted Bracht's Dolphin Smalltalk Tutorial:

http://www.amazon.co.uk/Dolphin-SmallTalk-Tutorial-Ted-Bracht/dp/0201737930

It takes you set-by-step through a GUI-based windows application. It's a pretty good tutorial.