# Is there any documentation for smalltalk language?

Tags: smalltalk

I was looking for smalltalk documentation to learn about its features and design not syntax, I just want to know the general features of this language and its design. like Message passing, Dynamic and strong typing, Reflection, Object-orientation....., thanks.

Comment: Can you define good? Do you need tutorial material, or a reference manual? A quick Google search turns up lots of material.

Answer (score 4):

If you searched a little longer you could have found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461052/smalltalk-learning-project-any-recommendation?rq=1)...

Within that question there are many links to different documentation/tuts in which you may find helpful.